# Brenn-nessel/Bren-nnessel

Tags: hyphenation

Ich weiß, dass, wenn es zwei gleiche Konsonanten oder Vokale gibt, man das Wort zwischen diese Buchstaben trennt, zum Beispiel: *beenden – be-enden, Trimmer – Trim-mer.*

Aber es gibt keine geschriebenen Regeln, die sagen, wie man Wörter, die mehrere Konsonanten oder Vokale haben, trennen soll, sodass ich wirklich möchte, dass Sie mir sagen, wie man solche Wörter trennen soll. Zum Beispiel: *Brennnessel,  Fitnessstudio.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zusammengesetze Wörter solltest du an der Wortgrenze trennen.

[Der Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/worttrennung#D167:) sagt:

> Zusammengesetzte Wörter und Wörter mit Präfixen (Vorsilben) werden nach ihren Bestandteilen getrennt <§ 108>.

Für deine Beispiele bedeutet das, dass nur

- *Brenn - nessel*
- *Fitness - studio*

korrekt sind.

Answer (score 3):

Zusätzlich zu der Antwort von Jonathan Schoolbach, die die geltende Regel klar darstellt: Im Deutschen und den meisten anderen europäischen Sprachen gibt es keine Wörter, die mit zwei gleichen Konsonanten beginnen.

Deshalb wird bei drei gleichen Konsonanten hintereinander im sprachlichen Alltag nach dem zweiten getrennt, und man kann einfach mechanisch vorgehen.

> Sauerstoff()flasche
> Schiff()fahrt

Die wenigen, eher theoretischen, Ausnahmen sind Zusammensetzungen mit Fremdwörtern aus Sprachen, in denen zwei Konsonanten an Wortanfang vorkommen (Lloyd, Llano, Llanfairpwll­gwyngyllgogery­chwyrndrobwll­llantysilio­gogogoch).

Bei Vokalen ist das anders, es gibt im Deutschen eine kleine Anzahl Wörter und eine größere Anzahl Eigennamen, die mit doppelten Vokalen beginnen (Aal, Aas, Aachen, Aalen, Oos ...).